# Connect Function App to CosmosDB with Managed Identity

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to write a function in a Function App that manipulates data in a CosmosDB. I get it working if I drop the read-write key in the environment variables. To make it more robust I wanted it to work as a managed identity app. The app has the role 'DocumentDB Account Contributor' on the Cosmos DB.

However, the CosmosClient constructor doesn't accept a Credential and needs the read-write key. I've been chasing down the rabbit hole of azure.mgmt.cosmosdb.operations where there is a `DatabaseAccountsOperations` class with a `list_keys()` method. I can't find a neat way to access that function though. If I try to create that object (which requires poaching the config, serializer and deserializer from my dbmgmt object) it still requires the `resourceGroupName` and `accountName`.

I can't help but think that I've taken a wrong turn somewhere because this has to be possible in a more straightforward manner. Especially given that the JavaScript SDK references a more logical class [CosmosDBManagementClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/arm-cosmosdb/cosmosdbmanagementclient) in line with the SubscriptionClient. However, I can't find that class anywhere on the python side.
Any pointers?

```py
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient
from azure.mgmt.resource import SubscriptionClient
from azure.mgmt.cosmosdb import CosmosDB
from .cred_wrapper import CredentialWrapper

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    request_body = req.get_body()
    # credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    # https://gist.github.com/lmazuel/cc683d82ea1d7b40208de7c9fc8de59d
    credential = CredentialWrapper()  

    uri = os.environ.get('cosmos-db-uri')
    # db = CosmosClient(url=uri, credential=credential)  # Doesn't work, wants a credential that is a RW/R key
    # Does work if I replace it with my primary / secondary key but the goal is to remove dependence on that.

    subscription_client = SubscriptionClient(credential)
    subscription = next(subscription_client.subscriptions.list())

    dbmgmt = CosmosDB(credential, subscription.subscription_id)  # This doesn't accept the DB URI??
    operations = list(dbmgmt.operations.list())  # I see the list_keys() Operation there...
```

---

#### EDIT

A helpful soul provided a response here but removed it before I could even react or accept it as the answer. They pointed out that there is an equivalent [python SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-cosmosdb/azure.mgmt.cosmosdb.cosmosdbmanagementclient?view=azure-python) and that `from azure.mgmt.cosmosdb import CosmosDBManagementClient` would do the trick.

From there, I was on my own as that resulted in

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'CosmosDBManagementClient' from 'azure.mgmt.cosmosdb'
```

I believe the root of the problem lies in an incompatibility of the package `azure-mgmt`. After removing `azure-mgmt` from my `requirements.txt` and only loading the cosmos and identiy related packages, the import error was resolved.

This solved 90% of the problem.

```py
dbmgmt  = CosmosDBManagementClient(credential, subscription.subscription_id, c_uri)
print(dbmgmt.database_accounts.list_keys())
```

```
TypeError: list_keys() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'resource_group_name' and 'account_name'
```

Does one really need to collect each of these parameters? Compared to the [example that reads a secret from a Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-authenticate#authenticate-with-defaultazurecredential) it seems so convoluted.

Comment: That helpful soul was Steve Zhao (God bless him :)). He did include code for `CosmosDBManagementClient` however that client is for performing management operations on your Cosmos DB account. What you're looking for is to perform data operations using managed identity. I pointed this out to him and that's why he deleted his answer.

Comment: Also, your `list_keys()` method will only work as long as there is no management lock on your Cosmos DB account.

Comment: Yes, both `resource_group_name` and `account_name` parameter is required in `list_keys` method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-cosmosdb/azure.mgmt.cosmosdb.operations.databaseaccountsoperations?view=azure-python#list-keys-resource-group-name--account-name----kwargs-

Comment: Thank you both for your helpful comments. After more digging it seems that managed identity access from a function app to cosmos is not yet support as of May 2021. [MS Forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/33896353-support-msi-managed-service-identity-direct-acce). From a SO etiquette, do I close my question with that answer or what is the way to go?

Comment: @Sebastiaan You can post an answer to end this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For other unfortunate ones looking to access CosmosDB with Managed Identity, it seems that this is, as of May 2021, not yet possible.

Source: Discussion on [Github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/29762)

Answer (score 0):

**Update 12/05/2021** - I came here finding a solution for this with Javascript/Typescript. So leaving the answer here for others. I think that a similar approach could work for Python.

You can use RBAC for data plane operations with Managed Identities. Finding the documentation was difficult.

[RBAC for Cosmos DB data plane operations with Managed Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac)

**Important** -  If you get the error *Request blocked by Auth mydb : Request is blocked because principal [xxxxxx-6fad-44e4-98bc-2d423a88b65f] does not have required RBAC permissions to perform action Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/readMetadata on resource [/].* **Don't use the Portal to assign roles, use the Azure CLI for CosmosDB.**
[How to - creating a role assignment for a user/system MSI/user MSI is done using the Azure CosmosDB CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac#role-assignments)

```sh
# Find the role ID:

resourceGroupName='<myResourceGroup>'
accountName='<myCosmosAccount>'
az cosmosdb sql role definition list --account-name $accountName --resource-group $resourceGroupName

# Assign to the MSI or user managed MSI:

readOnlyRoleDefinitionId = '<roleDefinitionId>' # as fetched above
principalId = '<aadPrincipalId>'
az cosmosdb sql role assignment create --account-name $accountName --resource-group $resourceGroupName --scope "/" --principal-id $principalId --role-definition-id $readOnlyRoleDefinitionId
```

Once this step is done, the code for connecting is very easy. Use the @azure/identity package's Default Credential. **This works in Azure Function App with managed identity and on your laptop with VS code or with `az login`**.

[Docs for @azure/identity sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/identity)

[Examples of authentication with @azure/identity to get the credential object](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/identity/identity/samples/AzureIdentityExamples.md#authenticating-in-azure-with-managed-identity)

[image: Azure identity default credential]

```js
import { CosmosClient } from "@azure/cosmos";
import { DefaultAzureCredential, ManagedIdentityCredential, ChainedTokenCredential } from "@azure/identity";

const defaultCredentials = new DefaultAzureCredential();
const managedCredentials = new ManagedIdentityCredential();
const aadCredentials = new ChainedTokenCredential(managedCredentials, defaultCredentials);
        
client = new CosmosClient({
                endpoint: "https://mydb.documents.azure.com:443/",
                aadCredentials
            });
```