# Connect Azure CosmosDB using Managed Identities from Azure Function App both locally and on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-managed-identity

I create a Managed Identity for a Function app and assigned it to `DocumentDB Account Contributor` by following the two sections below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/managed-identity-based-authentication#assign-a-system-assigned-managed-identity-to-a-function-app

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/managed-identity-based-authentication#grant-access-to-your-azure-cosmos-account

**Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication**

I got an exception when I tried to run the code from the section below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/managed-identity-based-authentication#programmatically-access-the-azure-cosmos-db-keys

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Encodings.Web,
> Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
> The system cannot find the file specified.
> at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo.DeterminePropertyName()
> at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo.GetPolicies(Nullable`1 ignoreCondition, Nullable`1 declaringTypeNumberHandling)    at
> ...
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
> at
> Cosmos.Samples.AzureFunctions.AzureFunctionsCosmosClientMI.d__7.MoveNext()
> in
> C:.ME\MyLab.Code\AzureCode\CosmosDB\azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3-usage\AzureFunctions\AzureFunctionsCosmosClientMI.cs:line
> 85

**Azure.Identity**

Since `AppAuthentication` is not recommended by MS, then I switched to using `Azure.Identity` by following the links below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-dotnet

https://joonasaijala.com/2021/07/01/how-to-using-managed-identities-to-access-cosmos-db-data-via-rbac-and-disabling-authentication-via-keys/

and the code below

```
 static string cosmosUrl = "https://xxx.documents.azure.com:443/";
    private static CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(cosmosUrl, new DefaultAzureCredential());
   var container = client.GetContainer("FamilyDatabase", "FamilyContainer");
        try
        {
            var result = await container.CreateItemAsync<Item>(data, new PartitionKey(data.LastName));
            return new OkObjectResult(result.Resource.Id);
        }
        catch (CosmosException cosmosException)
        {
            log.LogError("Creating item failed with error {0}", cosmosException.ToString());
            return new BadRequestObjectResult($"Failed to create item. Cosmos Status Code {cosmosException.StatusCode}, Sub Status Code {cosmosException.SubStatusCode}: {cosmosException.Message}.");
        }
```

However, I got the exception below both locally and running it in Azure.

> Failed to create item. Cosmos Status Code Forbidden, Sub Status Code
> 5301: Response status code does not indicate success: Forbidden (403);
> Substatus: 5301; ActivityId: xxxx-bf03-4355-8642-5d316f9d3373;
> Reason: (Request blocked by Auth xxxx : Request is blocked because
> principal [xxx-2bff-44e9-97be-9ffeb3aae3ee] does not have
> required RBAC permissions to perform action
> [Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/readMetadata] on resource [/].
> Learn more: https://aka.ms/cosmos-native-rbac. ActivityId:
> xxx-bf03-4355-8642-5d316f9d3373,
> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0, Windows/10.0.14393
> cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.24.1);.

Locally, I logged into VS following the link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-dotnet#authenticating-via-visual-studio

Any idea for resolving issues with Azure.Identity?

Ref:

[Connect Function App to CosmosDB with Managed Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67512766/connect-function-app-to-cosmosdb-with-managed-identity)

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/Azure.Identity_1.5.0/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/samples

Answer (score 10):

I ran into this same error this morning while setting up CosmosDB to use the Managed Identity of my Azure VM. The error message states that your principal does not have the RBAC permission **Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/readMetadata**. Once you give the principal you are using that permission authentication using Azure.Identity should work.

The **DocumentDB Account Contributor** doesn't have the role **Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/readMetadata**, and I couldn't find a built in Azure role that contained that permission so I created my own custom **CosmosDBReadWrite** role by following the example in this [article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-architecture-blog/configure-rbac-for-cosmos-db-with-managed-identity-instead-of/ba-p/3056638).

To create the custom role definitions and assignments, you will need to have the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/) installed.

### Configuring Custom Role Definitions

##### Prepare JSON Role Definition File

First you will need to create a json file with the role definition. Here are 2 different custom role configuration json files, one for read-only access to the CosmosDB and the other has read-write role access.

###### Json file for read-only custom role

```
{
    "RoleName": "CosmosDBReadOnlyRole",
    "Type": "CustomRole",
    "AssignableScopes": ["/"],
    "Permissions": [{
        "DataActions": [
            "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/readMetadata",
            "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers/items/read",
            "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers/executeQuery",
            "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers/readChangeFeed"
        ]
    }]
}
```

###### Json file for read-write custom role

```
{
    "RoleName": "CosmosDBReadWriteRole",
    "Type": "CustomRole",
    "AssignableScopes": ["/"],
    "Permissions": [{
        "DataActions": [
            "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/readMetadata",
            "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers/items/*",
            "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers/*"
        ]
    }]
}
```

##### Create and Assign Role Definition

After you have your json file saved with your custom role definition, we can create the custom role with the Azure CLI and then assign it to the correct principal.

Create your custom role using the JSON file you created above

```
resourceGroupName='<myResourceGroup>'
accountName='<myCosmosAccount>'
az cosmosdb sql role definition create -a $accountName -g $resourceGroupName -b @role-definition.json
```

After you create the role, the definition of the created role should be returned. If not, use the following command to find the **roleDefinitionId** which can be found in the **name** property.

```
az cosmosdb sql role definition list --account-name $accountName -g $resourceGroupName
```

Finally, apply the custom role to your principal that needs permission to access CosmosDB.

```
resourceGroupName='<myResourceGroup>'
accountName='<myCosmosAccount>'
roleDefinitionId = '<roleDefinitionId>'
principalId = '<ID for the Object that needs access to the CosmosDB>'
az cosmosdb sql role assignment create -a $accountName -g $resourceGroupName -s "/" -p $principalId -d $roleDefinitionId
```

Hope this solves the error you are running into as well!

Comment: Thanks for this, I wonder why there is no built-in role with these permissions

Comment: Actually, CosmosDB Account Contributor does inlude this role as part of the wildcard -
Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/*

Comment: @KrutiJoshi I can't see the wildcard in the built in role DocumentDB Account Contributor.  All the permissions in the built in role has specifics under Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/...

Comment: Update(wasn't allow to edit my previous comment) - I tried to clone the built in role and add `readMetadata` and in their I can see the wildcard.

It also appears the `readMetadata` role doesn't exists...  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations
When creating a custom role via the portal, there isn't a `readMetadata` permission to select

Comment: +1 This answer is excellent. We followed the instructions and it solved our Cosmos DB access issues first time.

Answer (score 2):

Azure Cosmos DB actually has built-in roles for that.

For read only, roleDefinitionId is `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001`. For read and write, roleDefinitionId is `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002`. More details at [Configure role-based access control with Azure AD - Azure Cosmos Db | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac#built-in-role-definitions)

So all you need to do is give your principal the adequate permission.

```
az cosmosdb sql role assignment create -a <cosmosdbName> -g <resourceGroupName> -s "/" -p <principalId> -d 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002
```